# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Entrada as array

Tags: php, arrays

Who help me with this problem?

```
56    public static function mostrar_entradas_busqueda($entradas) {
57            $count = count($entradas);
58            for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
59                if ($i % 3 == 1) {
60                    ?>
61                    <div class="row"> 
62                        <?php
63                    }
64                    $entradas = $entradas[$i - 1];
65                    self::mostrar_entrada_busqueda($entradas);
66                    
67                    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
68                        ?>
69                    </div>
70                        <?php
71                    }
72                }
73                if ($i % 3 !== 0) {
74                    ?>
75                    </div>
76                    <?php
77                }
78            }
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Entrada as
>   array in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\EscritorEntradas.inc.php:64 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vistas\buscar.php(81):
>   EscritorEntradas::mostrar_entradas_busqueda(Object(Entrada)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\index.php(117):
>   include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\EscritorEntradas.inc.php on line 64

Comment: Please add `var_dump($entradas)` at the begging of your function and share the output - I afriad it will object and not array - if so try converting it to array before the `while` loop. and also rename the inner variable

Comment: That was my first thought as well. But check the edit (in that second answer, given by the OP); it seems that `$entradas` is a proper array, as at least once the loop's body is invoked (hence `Notice: Undefined variable: entrada` msg). It's rewriting the value that messes things up completely.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you execute it, this line...

```
$entradas = $entradas[$i - 1];
```

... rewrites the value of `$entradas` to an object (value of the very zeroth element of `$entradas` array). The next time you try to execute it, you essentially query that object as an array, hence the error.

Solution: just rename that variable, and you're done:

```
$entrada = $entradas[$i - 1]; // and now it's single
self::mostrar_entrada_busqueda($entrada);
```

And yes, variables are scoped per function in PHP, not per block. But even if the latter were the case, you'd still have to rewrite that line; I'm not aware of any language that has different rules of scope resolution for right and left parts of assignment statements.

As a sidenote, I'm really not sure why you check for `i % 3 == 0` inside `if (i % 3 == 1)` branch.

Comment: continue giving me error, I'll show you the other function and the error

Comment: Checked that other function; it doesn't do what you think it does. There's a subtle difference between `echo`, `print` and similar things in PHP and just going out of 'interpreter mode' with `<?php ... ?>`. You'll have to wrap that function's output somehow - with HEREDOC notation, output buffering or other means.

Comment: Muchas gracias raina77ow, no sabes cuanto te agradezco, bastante amable.